# when to use shared variables

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, oop

I have built a class which is instantiated many times in a list using vb.net. I want to persist an ID across all instantiations of my class. It's a list of questions which will all have one questionnaire ID. So I can do this whilst assigning the id to each question in the list. Ideally I would like to just assign the ID once and have it available in all the list objects.

So here is my shared member of a class along with property procedure for accessibilty.

```
 Public Class Questions
     Private Shared _questionnaireUID As Integer

    Public Shared Property QuestionnaireUID() As Integer
    Get
        Return _questionnaireUid
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _questionnaireUid = value
    End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

I started to use a vb.net shared class level variable and assigned through a property procedure. This seemed like the right approach, although now I have built it I can see that the shared variable is accessible throughout the entire application.

So like this for instantiation and assignment.

```
    Questions.QuestionnaireUID = CInt(questionnaireUID)
```

I dont even need to instantiate the class. So I now just have a global variable. to get around this I would use a class level variable instead of. I wondered if there is another way to just make the variable shared across the class and it's instantiated objects without assigning to each object and without making it available across the entire application. Is there a step I am missing.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: why not a `Questionnaire` class which contains a collection of `Questions`; the ID might then be ReadOnly and set via the constructor.  Shared doesnt seem to me to have a role in this

Comment: A shared variable is a global variable. This mean all questionnaire will have the same id. Unless this is used as the sequence, I don't see why the questionnaireUid should be shared.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am C# but that is not how I would go about it.
Have a class for the questionnaire

```
public class Questionnaire
{
   public Int ID { get; private set; }
   public List<Question> Questions  { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is a good point. I feel silly now. Of course this is the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think a shared (static) is really useful if you want to share something in the whole application. 
If I understand you right, you indeed have a class and would like to share one ID, but this ID is not interesting for the whole application but only for a questionnaire (a list of questions). For this, using shared is bad, because you will have to take care of the cleaning of this value once you're finished.

My question is, why do you instantiate the question list every time that you have a new question? Why don't putting the question list as a singleton?

Comment: I only do it once and then loop through it. Then I store it in a session and pick it up again. I would only recreate it if it is a new questionnaire or user.

Comment: So I shall just add the same questionnaireID to each element in my list of questions. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Yes, this is what I would do. You could create a class that contain the list and add the ID as property of the collection. This way, every time you add a new question, you could pass automatically the ID.

Answer (score 0):

Just because the private field is `Shared`, that does not mean that the property that accesses it also has to be `Shared`.  For instance, you could do this:

```
Public Class Questions
    Private Shared _questionnaireUID As Integer

    Public Property QuestionnaireUID() As Integer  ' Note, this is not Shared
        Get
            Return _questionnaireUid
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _questionnaireUid = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

When you do that, all `Questions` objects will always share the same value for that property, but the value will not be accessible through the class (without instantiating an object).

However, it's worth pointing out that, while that does encapsulate the value a little better as far as scope is concerned, it's still global state.  It doesn't really avoid most of the problems which are caused by having global variables.  The objects of that class will still behave in potentially unpredictable ways just as with any other kind of global state.  It also makes it so that you cannot have `Questions` objects working on two different ID's at the same time.

As an alternative, you may want to look into injecting the ID in the `Questions` class' constructor.  If passing it in each time you create one is too much of a pain, you could make it easier with a factory, for instance:

```
Public Class QuestionsFactory
    Public Sub New(questionnaireId As Integer)
        _questionnaireId = questionnaireId 
    End Sub

    Private _questionnaireId As Integer

    Public Function NewQuestions() As Questions
        Return New Questions(_questionnaireId)
    End Function
End Class
```